# filter by letter in datatables not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables to show some pricelist, I filter the prices by letter.
the problem that I have is when I click on the letter it shud pass it to the proccesing file(bronze.fnReloadAjax) but is not.
Instead I get all the records because href is empty

```
$(".whitelinks a").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
 link = $(this).attr("href");
 href = link.substring(1);
  bronze.fnReloadAjax('price_list/plan_bronze.php?selection='+href);
 });
```

Comment: So the value of link is empty too?

Comment: When I do 

alert(link);

I get the letter. But when I do

alert(href);

It comes back empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the link is only a single letter, `href = link.substring(1)` removes the first letter of the link. This means it will be blank.